# How to open Xaml, XML in visual studio?

Tags: xml, xaml

HI guys I have an XML file with code like this:

```
<![CDATA[

import clr, time
from datetime import datetime, date

clr.AddReference('mscorlib')
clr.AddReference('PresentationCore')
...
]]>
```

and a corresponding XAML file.

What language is this? and can you tell me how I can open this in an IDE and play with the code?

Thanks

Jen

Answer (score 0):

This is C#. You can use it inside the xml to do view related things. Edit it with any editor. Visual Studio probably is the best IDE for it.

For an example and deeper explainiation check out [inline c# in xaml 1](https://elegantcode.com/2010/12/14/yes-you-can-write-inline-code-in-xaml/)
and [inline c# in xaml 2](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42980/How-to-embed-a-C-code-into-an-XAML-file)

Comment: Thanks but it does not look like c# here is some more code:
def Init(sender, eventArgs):
  subRefreshStats()

Comment: I see. Usually it is c# (most common), F# or Visual basic, but none of those has a `def` keyword. Maybe post the whole file and where you got it from. is the CDATA even in a `<x:code>` tag?